# Why AWS.S3 getObject().createReadStream() doesn't return data while getObject().promise() does?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I created a Lambda function that is invoked every time a file is added to my bucket.
I want my Lambda function to read the file that added as a steam from the bucket and save it in another bucket, so I wrote a code using aws-sdk with NodeJS that supposed to do that:

```
...
try {
    const file = s3 
        .getObject({ Bucket: srcBucket, Key: srcKey })
        .createReadStream();
    console.log(file);

    const destParams = {
        Bucket: dstBucket,
        Key: dstKey,
        Body: file,
    };
    await s3.putObject(destParams).promise();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

I tested my code by uploading a file to the bucket, and after the function invoked I checked the logs and saw this error:

```
INFO    Error: Cannot determine length of [object Object]
```

So I checked the console.log of the file variable and saw that object:

```
2021-04-02T08:52:40.642Z    3641187f-4d79-44e1-89f4-45c7e1967816    INFO    PassThrough {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
  },
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { prefinish: [Function: prefinish] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState: WritableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    finalCalled: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    destroyed: false,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: true,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    afterWriteTickInfo: null,
    buffered: [],
    bufferedIndex: 0,
    allBuffers: true,
    allNoop: true,
    pendingcb: 0,
    prefinished: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
    errored: null,
    closed: false
  },
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kTransformState)]: {
    afterTransform: [Function: bound afterTransform],
    needTransform: false,
    transforming: false,
    writecb: null,
    writechunk: null,
    writeencoding: null
  }
}
```

Then, for debugging I tried to do that without steams, so instead of using createReadStream () I used .promise():

```
try {
    const file = await s3 
        .getObject({ Bucket: srcBucket, Key: srcKey })
        .promise()
    console.log(file);

    const destParams = {
        Bucket: dstBucket,
        Key: dstKey,
        Body: file.Body,
    };
    await s3.putObject(destParams).promise();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

In this way it worked well.

I have no clue what is wrong with the createReadStream function.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try using s3.upload to upload a stream to s3. It will handle chunking the file and using a multipart upload behind the scenes if needed.

Also if you are just copying the file from S3 to S3 consider using S3 replication or s3.copyObject instead.